# radio button not checking the checked button

Tags: html

Even the second radio is checked its not checking that and keep the last one checked

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_1" name="room[bed_room]" value="1" checked="false" />
  <label for="bed_room_1">1</label>
  </input>

  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_2" name="room[bed_room]" value="2" checked="true" />
  <label for="bed_room_2">2</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_3" name="room[bed_room]" value="3" checked="false" />
  <label for="bed_room_3">3</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_4" name="room[bed_room]" value="4" checked="false" />
  <label for="bed_room_4">4+</label>
  </input>
</div>
```

Codepen link [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGeVpW)

Comment: I don't understand what you need?

Comment: Just remove all others checked attribute it will work

Comment: @abhilash are you trying to check more than one radio button?

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper This snippet is just for one and yes I do have more buttons in my form..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

checked in radio button is not an **attribute** that accepts true or false. It is a **property**. so either **checked** will work
or **checked = "checked"** will work

```
<input type="radio" id="bed_room_2" name="room[bed_room]" value="2" checked />
<label for="bed_room_2">2</label>
```

for more
[Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)

Difference b/w property and attribute

http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/attribute-vs-property/

Comment: _“so only __checked__ will work”_ – not “only”, `checked="checked"` is also allowed (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute) – and _necessary_, if one wants to write XML-compatible code, because that does not allow “stand-alone” attributes without a value.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe,  i have udpated

Comment: Thank you for the links..Its actually dynamically generated so it was easier for me to work with boolean values..Never thought like this..Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

`checked="false"` is not valid. You should use `checked` or `checked="checked"` to specify the input to check:

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_1" name="room[bed_room]" value="1" />
  <label for="bed_room_1">1</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_2" name="room[bed_room]" value="2" checked />
  <label for="bed_room_2">2</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_3" name="room[bed_room]" value="3" />
  <label for="bed_room_3">3</label>
  </input>
  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_4" name="room[bed_room]" value="4" />
  <label for="bed_room_4">4+</label>
  </input>
</div>
```